# db_query in drupal insert the values as question marks

Tags: mysql, drupal

when i use db_query in drupal to insert non-english letters (Arabic for example), it appears as question marks in the DB, while if i use mysql_query it works fine !!!
any idea about this and how to fix it??

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the database connection encoding set to? (mysql_client_encoding is the PHP function) Also, what version of MySQL are you using and does Drupal correctly output the characters on the front-end?

Comment: utf8, and mysql version is 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 and drupal shows them as question marks as well

Comment: Where is the content coming from? (Via drupal itself, or a MySQL import or ?)

Comment: sorry the mysql_client_encoding is latin1 not utf8
but the table itself is utf8,,,
the data comes from drupal itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks all for your attention...
i fixed this issue by using
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll need to set the mysql_client_encoding to use UTF8, although you'll want to check if the table character set and collation, etc. are set to this as well.

i.e.: The table definitions should ideally be of the form...

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
...

) ENGINE=... DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

(That said, that will of course use a case insensitive collation, which you might not desire/require.)

In essence, as long as you use UTF8 throughout (front end page encoding, mysql client connection encoding and table collation, etc.) you shouldn't have any problems.